# Calling an API every n seconds and stop calling when the values of api response meets a requirement in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
    this.state = {response:{},requirementMeets:false,}
    componentDidMount = ()=>{this.getAPI()}
    componentDidUpdate = ()=>{
if(requirementMeets===false){
setInterval(this.getAPI, 3000)
}
}
getAPI = async()=>{
.....
if (response==true){
this.setState = ({
response:response,
});
if(//response meets condition//){
this.setState({
requirementMeets:true
})
}
else{
this.setState({
requirementMeets:false
})
}
}
}
```

Here i want to call the api for every 30s untill requirement meets in the response, when requirement is met i would like to stop calling the API.How can i achieve this?

Comment: I don't know React JS but you can achieve this by using try catch and do while in Java

Comment: You could try calling [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) when the requirements are met. Also, I'm not as familiar with class components, but if you keep calling [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), you may end up with multiple running.